# 18.04 Nvidia Drivers Causing Freezing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, 18.04

I installed the Nvidia 390 driver on Ubuntu 18.04 on my late-2013 rMBP, but now my computer freezes constantly/randomly when I:

- Open a new app (almost always)
- Close a new app (rarely)
- Try to adjust my monitor settings (like positioning) (100% of the time)

How can I fix this?